# numpy inverse matrix not working for full rank matrix - hessian in logistic regression using newtons-method

Tags: numpy, logistic-regression, matrix-inverse, newtons-method, hessian

I am trying to compute the inverse of a full-rank matrix using numpy, but when  I test the dot product, I find that it does not result in the identity matrix - which means it did not invert properly.

My code:

```
H = calculateLogisticHessian(theta, X) #returns a 5x5 matrix
Hinv = np.linalg.inv(H)
print("H = " + str(H))
print("Hinv = " + str(Hinv))
I = np.dot(H, Hinv)
isIdentity = np.allclose(I , np.eye(5))
print("invdotinv = " + str(isIdentity) + "\n" + str(I))
```

and the output:

```
H = [[  77.88167948   81.49914902   85.11661855   88.73408809   92.35155763]
 [  81.49914902   85.36097831   89.2228076    93.0846369    96.94646619]
 [  85.11661855   89.2228076    93.32899665   97.4351857   101.54137475]
 [  88.73408809   93.0846369    97.4351857   101.7857345   106.1362833 ]
 [  92.35155763   96.94646619  101.54137475  106.1362833   110.73119186]]
Hinv = [[  1.41918134e+02   1.00000206e+08  -1.00000632e+08  -9.99999204e+07
    1.00000205e+08]
 [  1.00000347e+08   1.00000647e+08  -4.00001421e+08   9.99994941e+07
    1.00000932e+08]
 [ -1.00000916e+08  -4.00001424e+08   8.00003700e+08   5.68436971e+02
   -3.00001928e+08]
 [ -9.99997780e+07   1.00000065e+08  -5.72321511e+02   1.00000063e+08
   -9.99997769e+07]
 [  1.00000205e+08   1.00000505e+08  -3.00001073e+08  -1.00000205e+08
    2.00000567e+08]]
invdotinv = False
[[  1.00000000e+00  -3.81469727e-06  -7.62939453e-06   3.81469727e-06
    3.81469727e-06]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.00000191e+00  -1.52587891e-05   3.81469727e-06
    0.00000000e+00]
 [ -3.81469727e-06   1.90734863e-06   9.99992371e-01   3.81469727e-06
    3.81469727e-06]
 [  1.90734863e-06  -1.90734863e-06  -7.62939453e-06   1.00000191e+00
    3.81469727e-06]
 [  0.00000000e+00  -1.90734863e-06   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    1.00000000e+00]]
```

As you can see the `np.dot(H, Hinv)` matrix does not return identity and results in `False` when evaluating `np.allclose(I , np.eye(5))`.

What am I doing wrong?

**Later edit**

this is the function which calculates the hessian:

```
def calculateLogisticHessian(theta, X):
    '''
    calculate the hessian matrix based on given function, assuming it is some king of logistic funciton
    :param theta: the weights
    :param x: 2d array of arguments
    :return: the hessian matrix
    '''
    m, n = X.shape
    H = np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(0,m):
        hxi = h(theta, X[i])   #in case of logistic, will return p(y|x)
        xiDotxiT =  np.outer(X[i], np.transpose(X[i]))
        hxiTimesOneMinHxi = hxi*(1-hxi)
        currh = np.multiply(hxiTimesOneMinHxi, xiDotxiT)
        H = np.add(H, currh)
    return np.divide(H, m)
```

which should be according to the hessian calculation formula in andrew ng's video regarding newtons method for logistic regression:

https://youtu.be/fF-6QnVB-7E?t=5m6s
at 5:06

> 1/m * (SUM from i=1 till m of[h(X[i]) * (1 - h(X[i]) * (X[i] *
>   X[i]'T)])

where X is the 2x2 matrix of data and h() is the function based on theta (theta is the weigts) which in this case returns the logistic function.

the inputs I used:

```
theta = np.array([0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005])
X = np.array(range(5*7))
X = X.reshape((7,5))

H = calculateLogisticHessian(theta, X)
```

so is there an error in the way I iplemented the hessian formula or is the issue in the inputs, and what is the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure one can invert this matrix? The determinant is approximately zero: `np.linalg.det(H)` gives `-5.9450505443953825e-24` which is below numerical insecurities which I would name somewhere around `1e-15`. Also try to print `I` and read the docs of `np.allclose`.

Comment: I am not sure the matrix can be inverted. I added an explanation regarding how I got to that matrix

Answer (score 2):

Hessian matrix are often [ill-conditioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number).  [`numpy.linalg.cond`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cond.html)
lets you compute the *condition number*:

```
In [188]: np.linalg.cond(H)
Out[188]: 522295671550.72644
```

Since the condition number of `H` is large, computing its inverse has rounding issues .

Comment: I see, I did not learn numerical analysis yet. So how do people usually deal with hessian matrix inversion? I know this is required for methods such as logistic regression newtons method.